# t-sql condition placement

Tags: t-sql, where-clause, inner-join

Should SQL Server yield the same results for both of the queries below? The primary difference is the condition being placed in the WHERE clause with the former, and with the latter being placed as a condition upon the join itself.

```
SELECT *
FROM cars c
INNER JOIN parts p
   ON c.CarID = p.CarID
WHERE p.Desc LIKE '%muffler%'

SELECT *
FROM cars c
INNER JOIN parts p
   ON c.CarID = p.CarID
   AND p.Desc LIKE '%muffler%'
```

Thanks in advance for any help that I receive upon this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `INNER JOINS` it will make no difference to semantics or performance. Both will give the same plan. For `OUTER JOIN`s it does make a difference though.

```
/*Will return all rows from cars*/
SELECT c.*
FROM cars c
LEFT JOIN parts p
   ON c.CarID = p.CarID AND c.CarID <> c.CarID


/*Will return no rows*/
SELECT c.*
FROM cars c
LEFT JOIN parts p
   ON c.CarID = p.CarID 
WHERE c.CarID <> c.CarID
```

For inner joins the only issue is clarity. The `JOIN` condition should (IMO) only contain predicates concerned with how the two tables in the `JOIN` are related. Other unrelated filters should go in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

For inner joins the two queries should yield exactly the same results. Are you seeing a difference?

Comment: No, I am not. It's actually just something that I've wondered a few hundred times over the past couple of years, but up til now neglected to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they both get the same results. The difference is *when* the condition is checked, if during the join or afterwards.

Comment: No, same execution plan and cost. You can use either one.

Answer (score 0):

The execution plan will be identical in your example.  Next to the parse button should be the "Show execution plan" button.  It will give you a clearer picture.

I think in a more complex query with many joins it can be an issue in efficiency, as stated above, before or after.

EDIT: sorry assuming your using sql server management studio.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation for this kind of situation would be:

- put the `JOIN` condition (what establishes the "link" between the two tables) - and only that `JOIN` condition - after the `JOIN` operator
- any additional conditions for one of the two joined tables belongs in the regular `WHERE` clause

So based on that, I would always recommend to write your query this way:

```
SELECT
     (list of columns)
FROM 
     dbo.cars c
INNER JOIN 
     dbo.parts p ON c.CarID = p.CarID
WHERE 
     p.Desc LIKE 'muffler%'
```

It seem "cleaner" and more expressive that way - don't "hide" additional conditions behind a `JOIN` clause if they don't really belong there (e.g. help establish the link between the two tables being joined).